# Firebase Remote Config getString includes quotation marks

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-remote-config

I'm using RemoteConfig to fetch API Key. But when I log the fetched API key `Timber.d("API Key: $API_KEY")` it printed with quotation marks: `D/YoutubeDataApiRepositor: API Key: "SOMEAPIKEY"`

This makes the API failed to fetch data. When I hardcoded the API Key it works just fine.

remote_config_defaults.xml:

```
    <entry>
        <key>youtube_data_api_key</key>
        <value>SOMEAPIKEY</value>
    </entry>
```

Firebase RemoteConfig:
[image]

Code to retrieve:

```
private val API_KEY = RemoteConfigRepository.getYoutubeDataApikey()

//RemoteConfigRepository
fun getYoutubeDataApikey(): String = remoteConfig.getString("youtube_data_api_key")
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Try just removing the quotes from the value in the Firebase console.  I can only imagine they are being taken literally.

Comment: It'll say ```Invalid JSON```

Comment: Don't use the JSON editor button on the right - you don't have JSON here.  Just update the value without quotes.